# ID is not shown if using header in PHP instead of usual HTML link

Tags: php, html

```
 <a    href='page.php?id=$_SESSION[id]'>My page</a>
```

In this case it will look like `page.php?id=11`

But when I want to address to another page instead of showing the link, which must be clicked by user, I get `page.php?id=$_SESSION[id]`

```
header('Location: http:/page.php?id=$_SESSION[id]');
```

Why? How to change it?

Comment: *"In this case it will look like page.php?id=11"* - Will or "should"? What's the problem? Btw, you've a typo `http:/` missing a `/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using single quotes `'`, then you need to take the variable out of the string. You should also use the absolute address like this;

```
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/page.php?id=' . $_SESSION['id']);
```

Alternatively, you could use double quotes and then put curly braces around the variable (as it's an array variable).

```
header("Location: http://www.domain.com/page.php?id={$_SESSION['id']}");
```

---

Just thought I'd note that the second example is the preferred way of including variables in strings since the PHP compiler only has to store one thing in memory rather keep adding allocations when concatenating strings.

Comment: Beat me to it. As well you should probably use `"${_SESSION['id']}"` to avoid any weird adverse effects.

Comment: Btw, have you seen OP's *"But when I want to address to another page... I get `page.php?id=$_SESSION[id]`"*. I think it's a 2-part question ;-)

Comment: I read it as *When I do this it works ... but when I do this it doesn't*. Hopefully the OP can clarify if I have answered their question entirely.

Comment: OP's href *most probably* needs to be changed to `<a href='page.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION[id]; ?>'>My page</a>` - Far as I can tell, that's what the OP is saying is that `$_SESSION[id]` is showing up, instead of intended `id=11`. That's what I got out of the question; but that may just be me ;-)

Comment: The entire first string could be inside an `echo`, but I see where you're coming from.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about that also. We'll just wait for the OP's response. It's a bit unclear at this point.